# Blackberry SQLite out of memory on bind()

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, out-of-memory

I have quite a complex data access layer, which saves a lot of different data in an SQLite database. Everything works well, except when I try to save BLOBs which exceed 250 kb (maybe even smaller ones, but i have not tried).

Here is a SSCCE. If you run it in the simulator don't forget to simulate an SDCard before you start the app. I run it in 9700 simulator. Maybe you have to increase the byte array called "bigdata" on other devices. The out of memory error occurs in lin 67 "insert.bind(4, bigdata);"

What I would like to know is:
What is the memory in "out of memory"? Is it the RAM, the sdcard the SQLite cache?
What can I do about it? I HAVE TO use BB API 5.0, so I can't use the 6.0 methods for accessing BLOBs via streams.
Does anyone have a link to a list which explains how much memory has which BB device?
I read something about the memory limit. As far as I remember it was up to 1 MB guaranteed and more as long as the device RAM supports. 1 MB would be fine for my use, but 250 kb is not enough.
Any help is highly appreciated. I'm totally stuck, because i don't really know, where the limitation comes from. Thanks!

SSCCE:

```
    import net.rim.device.api.database.Database;
import net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseFactory;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Statement;
import net.rim.device.api.io.URI;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RichTextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class FirstSQLiteApp extends UiApplication
{

    public FirstSQLiteApp()
    {
        pushScreen(new InnerClassScreen());
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final FirstSQLiteApp firstSQLiteApp = new FirstSQLiteApp();
        firstSQLiteApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    class InnerClassScreen extends MainScreen
    {

        public Database sqliteDB;
        Statement       insert;
        Statement       s;
        byte[]          bigdata;

        public InnerClassScreen()
        {

            final LabelField title = new LabelField("Create DB Application", LabelField.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
            setTitle(title);
            add(new RichTextField("Initializing db create process..."));

            bigdata = new byte[250000];
            for (int i = 0; i < bigdata.length; i++)
            {
                bigdata[i] = 0x43;
            }

            try
            {
                final URI uri = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/blobtest.db");
                sqliteDB = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(uri);
                add(new RichTextField("Status: Database was successfully created."));
                s = sqliteDB.createStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (first LONG, second SMALLINT, third INTEGER, data1 BLOB, data2 BLOB )");
                s.prepare();
                s.execute();

                add(new RichTextField("Status: Table MyTable created."));

                insert = sqliteDB.createStatement("INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

                insert.prepare();

                final byte[] data2 = new byte[100];

                try
                {
                    insert.bind(1, 11111L);
                    insert.bind(2, (short) 222);
                    insert.bind(3, 3333);
                    insert.bind(4, bigdata); //HERE THE OUT OF MEMORY OCCURS
                    insert.bind(5, data2);

                    insert.execute();
                }
                catch (final Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("+++CUSTOM_OUTPUT+++" + e.getMessage());
                }

            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                add(new RichTextField("Status: Database was not created."));
                add(new RichTextField(e.getMessage()));
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    insert.close();
                    s.close();
                    sqliteDB.close();
                }
                catch (final Exception e)
                {
                    //amen
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i found this thread which seems to be quite similar, the "out of memory" just appears in another situation. http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/out-of-memory-issue-with-sqlite-database-on-blackberry-os-5-0/td-p/422172

Comment: I finally asked RIM and got the following answer:
gbeukeboom updated JAVAAPI-2241:
--------------------------------

    Status: Rejected  (was: Triage)

SQLite only has a finite amount of running memory available, this cannot be changed and is hard-set on all OS 5 devices. In OS 7 this increases:
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29270/BlackBerry_Java_SDK-New_In_This_Release--1634956-0603085932-001-7.0_Beta-US.pdf

For OS 5 it would be needed to perform smaller operations to avoid this error.

Please post to the forums if any support is needed.